# Removing lines from multiple files with sed command

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sed, zsh

So, disclaimer: I am pretty new to using bash and zsh, so there is a chance the answer is really simple. Nonetheless. I checked previous postings and couldn't find anything. (edit: I have tried this in both bash and zsh shells- same problem.)

I have a directory with many files and am trying to remove the first line from each file.

So say the directory contains: file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt ... etc.

I am using the sed command (non-GNU):

```
sed -i -e "1d" *.txt
```

For some reason, this is only removing the first line of the first file. I thought that the *.txt would affect all files matching the pattern in directory. Strangely, it is creating the file duplicates with -e appended, but both the duplicate and original are the same.

I tried this with other commands (e.g. ls *.txt) and it works fine. Is there something about sed I am missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using bash, or zsh?

Comment: I was under the impression that there was hardly a difference (for my beginner level at least). Currently I am using zsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different versions of `sed` in differing operating systems support various parameters.

### OpenBSD (5.4) sed

The `-i` flag is unavailable.  You can use the following `/bin/sh` syntax:

```
for i in *.txt
do
    f=`mktemp -p .` 
    sed -e "1d" "${i}" > "${f}" && mv -- "${f}" "${i}"
done
```

### FreeBSD (11-CURRENT) sed

The `-i` flag requires an extension, even if it's empty. Thus must be written as `sed -i "" -e "1d" *.txt`

### GNU sed

This looks to see if the argument following `-i` is another option (or possibly a command).  If so, it assumes an in-place modification.  If it appears to be a file extension such as "`.bak`", it will rename the original with the "`.bak`" and then modify it into the original file's name.

There might be other variations on other platforms, but those are the three I have at hand.

Comment: I will just *add* the POSIX version in text (taht is the OpenBSD Version). And try to use simple quote in sed action when available (avoiding any shell interpretation).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond to this, Gumnos. Your suggestion for the for-loop worked perfectly. Cheers!

Comment: Update to this answer: the `sed` in more recent versions of OpenBSD now has support for the `-i` flag in the same fashion as FreeBSD's.

Answer (score 2):

1. use it without -e !

for one file use:

```
sed -i '1d' filename
```

for all files use :

```
sed -i '1d' *.txt
```

or

```
files=/path/to/files/*.extension ; for var in $files ; do sed -i '1d' $var ; done
```

.for me i use ubuntu and debian based systems , this method is working for me 100% , but for other platformes i'm not sure , so this is other method :

2. replace first line with emty pattern , and remove empty lines , (double commands):

   for files in $(ls /path/to/files/*.txt); do sed -i "s/$(head -1 "$files")//g" "$files" ; sed  -i '/^$/d' "$files" ; done

Note: if your files contain splash '/' , then it will give error , so in this case sed command should look like this ( `sed -i "s[$(head -1 "$files")[[g"` )

hope that's what you're looking for :)

Comment: thank you for replying. I have BSD sed, so I have to provide some extension for "-i", otherwise I get an error. Even when I try the work-around of adding -i '' the same thing happens.

Comment: i'm not such a good linuxer , but i'll add more commands to this answer , hope it will help .

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, Younes. Got it all sorted out now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the line number isn't reset when sed opens a new file, so `1` only matches the first line of the first file.

One solution is to use a shell loop, calling sed once for each file. [Gumnos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30448136/2088135) shows how to do this in the most widely compatible way, although if you have a version of sed supporting the `-i` flag, you could do this instead:

```
for i in *.txt; do
    sed -i.bak '1d' "$i"
done
```

It is possible to avoid creating the backup file by passing an empty suffix but personally, I don't think it's such a bad thing. One day you'll be grateful for it!

---

It appears that you're not working with GNU tools but if you were, I would recommend using GNU awk for this task. The variable `FNR` is useful here, as it keeps track of the record number for each file individually, allowing you to do this:

```
gawk -i inplace 'FNR>1' *.txt
```

Using the `inplace` extension, this allows you to remove the first line from each of your files, by only printing the lines where `FNR` is greater than 1.

Testing it out:

```
$ seq 5 > file1
$ seq 5 > file2
$ gawk -i inplace 'FNR>1' file1 file2
$ cat file1
2
3
4
5
$ cat file2
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Thank you, Tom. I will definitely look into using awk for future tasks. (After looking at some of the documentation, it looks really powerful- albeit with a steep learning curve). I will look into getting GNU implementations as well. Thanks again, mate. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The last argument you are passing to the Sed is the problem
try something like this.

```
var=(`find *txt`)
for file in "${var[@]}"
do
    sed -i -e 1d $file
done
```

This did the trick for me.

Comment: Perfect! This worked really well. Thank you for taking the time to respond to the question!